# Can't go back to root from postgres: forces to enter postgres password which it finds invalid

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, database, sql

I've installed postgres on Ubuntu and it switched me to postgres user. I've opened `psql` created a database and then decided to switch back to root. However, it doesn't allow me:

```
sudo su -
```

results in it asking me

```
[sudo] password for postgres:
```

which I tried entering only to get

```
Sorry, try again
```

Then I decided to try to change postgres password using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721095/4759176):

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres';
```

It seemingly worked, but after trying to switch to root again, it still doesn't let me.

Comment: How did it switch you to `postgres`? Probably you used `sudo su postgres` or `sudo -u postgres -i`. In that case you just have to close the shell: `exit`, `logout` or simply `<CTRL>+D` on an empty line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you are confusing two things:

- `postgres` the system user
- `postgres` the SQL database user

The only relation between both is that at PostgreSQL installation, the *database* user `postgres` is authenticated with the [*peer* authentication method](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER): the database server checks that the *system* user requesting access to the database as database user `postgres` is also called `postgres`. Also, the database server itself runs as the system user `postgres`.

It's not possible from the database to alter the system. Giving a password on the database account will not alter the fact that the *system* user `postgres` has no *sudo* rights, and most certainly a disabled password, thus allowing only root to use it by default (but not the reverse).

So, if you want to become `root`, you cannot do this from the `postgres` system account, and that's a good thing: should ever the database server (its processes also running as system user `postgres`) be compromised, there will be no way to escalate to `root` access from it.

Just login again to the account you used to install postgreSQL: either directly the `root` account (usually not done on Ubuntu) or (usually done on Ubuntu) the user configured at installation of the system, with uid 1000, which on Ubuntu is allowed by default to do `sudo su -`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exit the postgres user, just type "exit".

It will go back to the root user